# when provided a value, looking to have the row number of the cell where that value resides

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please take a look at the following googleapps script code. the spreadsheet it references has 4 values in it. in a2 is the value "Two". I want that when I run this code, i receive an email with "2" in the subject line. I seem to keep on receiving a "4". Any ideas?

```
function rowofspecificvalue(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rMUrZFie94RLFDKaWVBPsQ-jebL8wNA6qsZWivMBDTk").getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getRange("a1:a4").getValues();
for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
if(data[i][1] == "Two"){ 
 Logger.log((i+1))
  return i+1;
  }
 } MailApp.sendEmail ("fake_email@gmail.com", i, "");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
MailApp.sendEmail("fake_email@gmail.com", i-2, "")
```

and you will "2" have in subject. Second argument of MailApp.sendEmail() function set up subject of email.

Comment: Hi Viktor,

Thanks for your answer. I wasnt clear. I am actually looking for a code that where "two" is from an external variable.  So I am looking for a code where if I entered "two", i would get  emailed "2". If "three" were entered, I would receive a "3". without having to change any other part of the code. I know that "i" is the wrong variable to put in the mailapp line. I am looking for the right variable to put in there.

Thanks